# How to open a .csv file and copy & paste a range to a new Excel Workbook using VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to use vba for a user press a button which lets them select a .csv workbook. Then the code will copy and paste a range to another workbook that is open. THis is my current code:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
FileToOpen = Application.GetOpenFilename _
(Title:="Open Report File", _
FileFilter:="Excel Files *.csv (*.csv),")
Dim sourceworkbook As Workbook
Dim currentworkbook As Workbook
Set currentworkbook = ThisWorkbook
Set sourceworkbook = Workbooks(FileToOpen)
sourceworkbook.Worksheets(1).Select.Range("B4:F4").Copy
currentworkbook.Activate
currentworkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Activate
currentworkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("B14:F14").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
sourceworkbook.Close
Set sourceworkbook = Nothing
Set currentworkbook = Nothing
ThisWorkbook.Activate
Worksheets("Sheet1").Activate
Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("B14").Select
End Sub
```

But i get "Run-time error '9": Subscript out of range" at the following step:

`Set sourceworkbook = Workbooks(FileToOpen)`

Is there a better way to achieve this?

Comment: Try `"Excel Files (*.csv), *.csv"`.

Comment: @VBasic2008 I have managed to get it to work. I made the change the following change to line 2:

`FileToOpen = Application.GetOpenFilename(FileFilter:="Excel workbook(*.csv),*.csv", Title:="Open Report File")`
i also changed:

`Set sourceworkbook = Workbooks(FileToOpen)' to 'Set sourceworkbook = Application.Workbooks.Open(FileToOpen)' and rmeoved '.Select' from 'sourceworkbook.Worksheets(1).Select.Range("B4:F4").Copy`
This now achieves the desired result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Import Range From Closed Workbook

```vb
Option Explicit

Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    
    Dim FilePath: FilePath = Application.GetOpenFilename( _
        FileFilter:="Excel Files (*.csv), *.csv", _
        Title:="Open Report File")
    
    If VarType(FilePath) = vbBoolean Then
        MsgBox "Canceled.", vbExclamation
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    Dim swb As Workbook: Set swb = Workbooks.Open(FilePath)
    Dim sws As Worksheet: Set sws = swb.Sheets(1) ' the one and only
    Dim srg As Range: Set srg = sws.Range("B4:F4")
    
    Dim dwb As Workbook: Set dwb = ThisWorkbook ' workbook containing this code
    Dim dws As Worksheet: Set dws = dwb.Sheets("Sheet1")
    Dim dfCell As Range: Set dfCell = dws.Range("B14")
    
    srg.Copy dfCell
    
    swb.Close SaveChanges:=False
    
    ' Probably not necessary:
    'If Not dwb Is ActiveWorkbook Then dwb.Activate
    'Application.Goto dfCell

    MsgBox "Range imported.", vbInformation

End Sub
```